# File read using contentsAtPath not working

Tags: objective-c

The following is my code and I have the newfile2 in the same directory as main.m is located(see image) but I am getting `File read failed` error. Where am I going wrong?

## import

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

```
@autoreleasepool {

    NSFileManager *fm;
    NSData *fileData;

    fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    //Read from the file nwefile2

    fileData = [fm contentsAtPath:@"newfile2"];

    if (fileData == nil) {
        NSLog(@"File read failed");
        return 1;
    }

    //Write the data to a file

    if ([fm createFileAtPath:@"newfile3" contents:fileData attributes:nil] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"File creation failed");
        return 2;
    }

    NSLog(@"File copy successful");
}
return 0;
}
```

[image: image showing the file structure]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this line doesn't say where to find the file:

```
fileData = [fm contentsAtPath:@"newfile2"];
```

You are *assuming* that a partial path will find the file (perhaps because you think the working directory is the same directory as your program?), but that is a false assumption. Nothing is known about what the working directory is! You have to be specific about where the file is.

Comment: will a string like this work? `~/Desktop/Obj-C Excercises/16/16.2/16.2/newfile2`

Comment: No, the `~` will not be meaningful. But you can munge using `stringByStandardizingPath:`.

Comment: I put my new file in the the directory which contains the executable file. It is working now.

Comment: Cool, but basically you are just hiding the problem from yourself. If you are trying to learn Objective-C, esp. for iOS or Mac OS X programming, it is going to be better practice to do it the right way. You will never use the "working directory" in real life; you will always specify a full path. So why not get used to it now?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to specify the path in-spite of hardcoding the path is use below api of NSBundle class:-

```
- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension
```

Write like that below:-

```
  fileData = [fm contentsAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                              pathForResource:@"newfile2" ofType:@"fileExt"]];
```

Note:- Before fetching the file path, your file should be present in the resource directory,.

Comment: Could you please tell me where this resource directory is?

Comment: Resource directory means it should be present in your bundle of app. Currently, where you have been placed the file is known as resource directory.